# Why does it throw error when I dont use List in the response_moedel?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic, uvicorn

so I was building a fastAPI app and I want my response model to get data from the database(in total 6 columns) and return that in the response description in the API.

```
@router.post("/run/new", response_model=schemas.xyzRun)
def new_request(*,
                          db: Session = Depends(get_db),
                          request: schemas.Request):

    id = service.initiate_new(db, request)
    return db.query(models.xyzRun).filter(models.xyzRun.xyzRunid == id).all()
```

I am just getting the value of the id from `service.initiate_new` and then returning the rows from the db which have that id.
It works when I put `response_model=List[schemas.xyzRun]` but the above code(without List) throws an error:
**pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 5 validation errors for EtlRun**

Can anyone please throw some light on this as I am lost?

Additional Information:
**models.xyzRun** is a class xyzRun where I have given the `__tablename__`,`__table_args__` and `xyzRunid = Column ('xyzRunid, Integer )` and 5 other variables.

**schemas.xyzRun** is aclass xyzRun where I have given `xyzRunid=int` and 5 other variables

Answer (score 1):

It's simple, your database founds multiple results and it comes inside a list, let's assume you have a model like this.

```py
class MyModel(BaseModel):
    name: str 
    value: str
```

And you have a database with two columns

```
Name | Value
------------
foo  | 1
bar  | 2
john | 3
jane | 4
```

When you send a request to the database and if it founds multiple results

The response would look something like this:

```py
[{"name": "foo", "value": 1}, {"name": "bar", "value", 2}, ...]
```

Pydantic tries to validate this but it founds a `List` instead of a `Dict` to validate, but when you tell it is a List it checks every item in that list. That is why it successfully returns the response with the `List`.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because using filter().all() returns a List and not a Dict i.e. it returns a set of records and not one single record.

```
db.query(models.xyzRun).filter(models.xyzRun.xyzRunid == id).all()
```

To fetch a single record you should use

```
db.query(models.xyzRun).filter(models.xyzRun.xyzRunid == id).first()
```

If you are always expecting a single record, you can also use .one() instead of .first()

Please check https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/tutorial.html#returning-lists-and-scalars for more reference.